# iOS autorotation. viewDidAppear execution happens before window was rotated

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface

I have view controller which can have any orientation. Next I change view controller like this:

```
let vc  = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    .instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CallScreen") as? CallViewController
vc!.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
navigationController.setViewControllers([vc!], animated: false)
```

The new view controller has only portrait orientation. When it appears on the screen happens following. View controller appears in landscape orientation (previous screen was landscape by chance). All elements are drawn for landscape orientation. And only than it rotates to portrait orientation, and elements of UI does not redraw to portrait orientation, has incorrect location and sizes.

In `viewDidAppear` I am checking for current orientation and initialize UI only if orientation is portrait. Also I am handling event when autorotation is finished (`viewWillTransition`). So if it fired I am initializing UI.
That's work but looks to complicated. The better way would be if view appeared already rotated to desired orientation.
Is there a way to do that?

Comment: You shouldn't be checking orientation at all. You should base all layout decisions on size. Use constraints to make it simpler. Such code doesn't belong in `viewDidAppear`. Set up all views and constraints in `viewDidLoad`. Adjust as needed in `viewWillTransition(to:with:)` if the initial constraints aren't sufficient.

Comment: I have constrains for UI elements. They are good for portrait mode, and I don't worry about landscape mode because view controller must be displayed in portrait mode only. But for short time it is displayed in landscape mode, that's somehow breaks everything.

Comment: The question is about how to display view in desired orientation immidiately. I know my constrains configured not the best way.